# How do I get rid of Tea fields?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I won the public lot for Tea and I want to the move crops on my farm over there (i already did...) but I want to free up the space on my farm that was the tea for something else (probably more cotton).

The thing is I've tried every tool at my disposal and the Tea bushes remained. How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tea fields are trees, chop them up with your Axe. Like normal trees, they won't fall on your first try (unlike crops with the Sickle), but keep going and they'll fall.

Comment: Hm, the axe didn't originally work. Then I learned it's just really finicky and you have to hit the "center" bush with it.